# Implementation of an OData v4 Endpoint for Large File Transfer in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, large-data, large-files

I am a novice in developing REST APIs in OData and am working on a project that requires the creation of an OData v4 endpoint in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData (v8.2.3) package. This endpoint will be responsible for generating and providing the client with a file, presumably large, in one of the following formats chosen by the client: CSV, JSON, or XML. The file will consist of tuples extracted from a database, so I expect a high volume of data to handle and transmit to the client. The resulting file will contain a list of objects serialized in the chosen format.

I have devised a possible solution that involves creating an OData function that accepts the desired file name as a parameter and returns the file to the client. However, I am facing some uncertainties:

Endpoint Design:

- Is it advisable to follow the OData function approach to implement this functionality?
- How would you go about this type of operation? Also, is the returned type for the EDM correctly Edm.Stream?

Data Transfer:
I have identified two possible strategies for data transfer:

a. **Serialization and Saving**:

- Execute a query on the database, serialize the data in the desired format, save them in a temporary file on the server, and finally transmit the file to the client.

b. **Paged Streaming**:

- Calculate the total number of elements to be transmitted, execute paginated queries on the database, serialize and begin transmitting to the client incrementally, page by page, until completion.

I would love to receive feedback or suggestions on these matters, particularly if there are other recommended approaches or best practices to consider for this type of operation. Thank you in advance for your help!

Code for Approach a.

```
[HttpGet("entity({id})/Functions.GetFile(fileName={fileName})")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetListFile(int id, string fileName)
{
    var accept = HttpContext.Request.Headers.Accept.ToString();

    // The Service creates the file in one of the formats and returns a MemoryStream.
    var memoryStream = await _service.GetStreamFileAsync(id);
    
    // Sending the file to the client
    return File(memoryStream, accept, fileName);
}
```